# Render only alpha values from texture

Tags: three.js

What i want to do is to load a texture with only alpha values from a PNG-picture while using the color of the material to render the RGB. To give you some context i use this for GPU-picking to find sprites that are clicked on. This way i can know if a sprite was clicked on or if the user clicked on the transparent part of the sprite.

I tried using the THREE.AlphaFormat as format and i tried all the types but 
what i get is a sprite with correct alpha, but the color from the texture is combined with the color of the material.

Here is the code i tried so far

```js
var type = THREE.UnsignedByteType;
var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( url );
spriteMap.format = THREE.AlphaFormat;
spriteMap.type = type;

var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap , color: idcolor.getHex() } ); //

var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );

sprite.position.set( this.position.x , this.position.y , this.position.z );
sprite.scale.set( this.scale.x , this.scale.y , this.scale.z );

Selection.GpuPicking.pickingScene.add( sprite );
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

three.js r.91

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to do what i wanted with combining texture and material. My solution was to create a plane and add my own custom shaders handling the Sprite functionality. I copied the shaders for sprites from three.js library and removed the code i didn't need since i only needed the correct alpha and one color to be visible.

My code for creating a sprite with color from material and alpha values from texture

```js
//Create the position, scale you want for your sprite and add the url to your texture
var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( url , function( texture ){

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1.0, 1.0 );

    uniforms = {
        color: {type:"v3", value: color },
        map: {value: texture },
        opacity: {type:"f", value: 1.0 },
        alphaTest: {type:"f", value: 0.0 },
        scale: {type:"v3", value: scale }    
   };

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
    {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: vertexShader, //input the custom shader here
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader, //input the custom shader here
        transparent: true,
    });


    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    mesh.position.set( position.x , position.y , position.z );
    mesh.scale.set( scale.x , scale.y ,sprite.scale.z );

    scene.add(mesh);

} );
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
uniform vec3 scale;
varying vec2 vUV;

void main() {

    float rotation = 0.0;
    vUV =  uv;

    vec3 alignedPosition =  position  * scale;

    vec2 rotatedPosition;
    rotatedPosition.x = cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x - sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
    rotatedPosition.y = sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x + cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;

    vec4 mvPosition;

    mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( 0.0, 0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 );
    mvPosition.xy += rotatedPosition;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;


}
```

my fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 vUV;
uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D map;
uniform float opacity;
uniform float alphaTest;

void main() {

    vec4 texture = texture2D( map, vUV );

    //showing the color from material, but uses alpha from texture
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color , texture.a * opacity ); 

    if ( gl_FragColor.a < alphaTest ) discard;

}
```